# What is .dhpcd command and how to disable it?

Tags: cpu-load

Nowadays, my laptop frequently uses high %CPU (300%). I noticed that `.dhpcd` is involved in high %CPU. I could kill the process without any issue. However, it turns on automatically in about every 30 minutes. Strangely, the user is `test` in `top`:

[image: screenshot of top]

I am wondering what it is and I would like to know how to fix or disable it completely (if it is okay). I am using Ubuntu 16.04.5.

`sudo crontab -l` showed `no crontab for root`.

From `sudo find / -iname "*dhpc*"` ,  I found this: `/home/test/.dhpcd`

This is the result of `ls -al`:

[image: ls -al output]

Quite a while ago, I created a git page just for practice. Something fishy is going on here..

Comment: Did you install a dhcp server?

Comment: Hi donghoon.
What ist the output of :
`sudo su test` and then `whicht .dhpcd` ?

Comment: Some sites seems to list that as a bad guy process.

Comment: Looks suspect - the name and resources are wrong. Could be a classic cryptominer (or other malware) masquerading as a system process. The REAL dhcp is a teeny little fellow that merely manages local IPV4 addresses. You can avoid malware like this by practicing safe computing habits. Removing it might be easy...or hard.

Comment: @George Udosen, I don't recall if I installed a dhcp server. In fact, I don't know what it is. Would you tell me how to check if I have installed a dhcp sever? @Boba Fit, `which .dhpcd` did not return anything (even if .dhpcd is running). @Doug Smythies, would you tell me the sources? and any suggestion? @user535733, if it is malware, how could i get rid of it?

Comment: Run `ls -l /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` and lets see!

Comment: @George Udosen, I didn't find `dhcpd.conf`, but have several files in `/etc/dhcp`. If I run `ls -l /etc/dhcp`,  I see `debug, dhclient.conf, ./dhclient-enter-hooks.d, ./dhclient-exit-hooks.d`

Comment: Ok those are your preinstall dhcpclient for querying a dhcp server!

Comment: I searched on google with `linux ".dhpcd"`. I think it is malware and it is very new.

Comment: @Doug Smythies, Thanks! This is good to know. I did not expect I would have malware with my linux machine; but I learned that it can happen to anyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to suggesting several things:

1. Unplug your system from the internet and see if that process is still seen in the `top` window. If gone then perhpas some one or process installed by some one is using your CPU perhaps for data minning. Then which ever try the steps below.
2. Search for it in:

   - cronjobs

     - `sudo crontab -l`: look for strange cronjobs
   - systemd services

     - `sudo find / -iname "*dhpc*"`
3. Use `top` and `ps`:

   - `top`:

     1. Start top
     2. press <kbd>f</kbd> and use the `arrow` keys to move and select all the `fields` that have to do with `user` and/or `userid` or `id` in general. See screen shot below.

        [image]
     3. Use the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> to select the fields and the press <kbd>q</kbd> to quit.

        [image]

Now see what `PPID`, `SUSER`, `RUSER`, `SUID` says about that process. To trace the culprit.

Comment: Shouldn't step 2 part 2 be `*dhpc*` instead of `*dhcp*`?

Comment: Yea your right let me update that!

Comment: @Doug Smythies, @George Udosen : Yes, I changed to `*dhpc*`.

Comment: @George Udosen, By the way, `.dhpcd` did not start offline. As soon as I turn online, the process started.

Comment: You created user test?

Comment: I don't think I created another user, but honestly, I don't recall..

Comment: Then you better remove that user `sudo userdel -r test`!

Comment: Okay! Is it going to be the final solution? If so, I will try it after answering vidarlo's question.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your help, especially, [George Udosen](https://askubuntu.com/users/459561/george-udosen) and [Doug Smythies](https://askubuntu.com/users/372967/doug-smythies).

Some of the things that I did were:

- `top` : To figure out which command was taking all my CPU; I found `.dhpcd` was using all my CPU. Note that it is different from `dhcpcd`.
- Googling with `linux ".dhpcd"`: To learn what it is...
- `sudo find / -iname "*dhpc*"` : To figure out which directory contained `.dhpcd`.
- `sudo userdel -r test` : To get rid of a user `test`. This was because `.dhpcd` was executed by a suspicious user called `test`.
- `sudo deluser --system --remove-all-files test` : To remove all files created by a user `test`.
- Finally I rebooted my laptop, and the issue has gone.

Note that I don't remember if I had created the user `test`. Since I don't use the account, I deleted everything related to it. I don't know if the issue would have been resolved by deleting only `.dhpcd`.

Answer (score 2):

I setup a server a week ago with a very weak password/username (`admin`:`admin`) and installed some intrusion detection system I wrote just to see what would happen.

It took just a few hours until the system got hacked and `.dhpcd`  was installed by a **malicious intruder**. The tool that hides behind `.dhpcd` is actually `xmrig` an open source **mining software**.

So, I strongly suggest that everyone who get's here asking what this program is to reformat your system and setup **better and more secure passwords**.

In case you wanna know, this is the tool I wrote and used to detect the intrusion the second it happened: https://github.com/snitch-ids/snitch

It basically sends you a message via telegram (or email) as soon as someone logs into your computer. It further detects changes made to your file system.

Answer (score 1):

These are bloody crypto miners `pool.supportxmr.com:80` stealing computing power, which in turn increases cloud budget and importantly uses all CPU, RAM, Swap, virtually leaving no room for your apps to run. The irony is that it looks like an authentic system process so no one gets suspicious of that.

If you kill the `PS` it'll restart automatically. Locate and delete the source, `cron` and all related files. To prevent it, don't relay on the default host password, make sure you download open-source software from the right repo and not from random places.

Also follow these steps:

1. Remove the file:

   ```
   rm -rf /home/{/path}/.dhpcd
   ```
2. List the `cron`:

   ```
   crontab -l [options]
   ```
3. Remove `cron`:

   ```
   crontab -r [options]
   ```